# Merge ClearCase elements to other branch but the branch doesn't show on GUI

Tags: merge, branch, clearcase

We have a problem with the ClearCase merging.

We had a **dev** branch and labeled it as **DEV_LABEL** after releasing. Then we created 2 new branches **dev1** and **dev2**.

[image]

The config specs of the dev1 and dev2 are:

**dev1**

```
 element * CHECKEDOUT
 element * /dev1/LATEST
 element * DEV_LABEL -mkbranch dev1
 element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch dev1
 element * /main/LATEST
```

**dev2**

```
 element * CHECKEDOUT
 element * /dev2/LATEST
 element * DEV_LABEL -mkbranch dev2
 element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch dev2
 element * /main/LATEST
```

The problem happened when we want to merge the **dev1** into the **dev2** branch. The **new** element in **dev1** cannot see the **dev2** branch, vice versa.

So that we are unable to merge the code from dev1 to dev2 branch.

[image]

The new element in the **dev1** has this branch path:

```
 @@/main/dev1
```

Are the config specs wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten the creation rule.

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /dev2/LATEST
element * DEV_LABEL -mkbranch dev2
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch dev2
element * /main/0 -mkbranch dev2   <====
element * /main/LATEST
```

A new element from `dev1` which doesn't exist in `dev2` would start from `/main/0`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are the best ClearCase answer here :)